# VM Exception while executing eth_estimateGas using for loop

Tags: solidity, testrpc, remix, ide

**Important:**

- Using [Solidity IDE](http://remix.ethereum.org/) with Web3 provider
- [Test RPC](https://github.com/ethereumjs/testrpc) and [web3](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/) installed
- Testing with 10 Ether accounts with enough Ether (100 ETH) per
  account.

I am testing a simple contract that receives Ether from one account, splits the value and transfers it to 3 other accounts.

```
contract testContract {

    address[] employees = [
        0x4cd28d9a0d66216382ad3e1c993797989d1a8e05,
        0xb871e16d7192cbaa2b5be32f85c1a19f61b8a50d,
        0x5e5527378c42b91e95fee2cfbe974259d983a99e
    ];

    function testContract() payable {

    }

    function () payable {
        uint amountPerEmployee = msg.value / employees.length;

        for(uint i = 0; i <= employees.length; i++) {
            employees[i].transfer(amountPerEmployee);
        }
    }

}
```

When running the callback function with the loop I get an error:

> callback contain no result Error: Error: VM Exception while executing
>   eth_estimateGas: invalid opcode
>       at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/build/cli.node.js:59368:17
>       at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/build/cli.node.js:69306:5
>       at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/build/cli.node.js:11335:9
>       at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/build/cli.node.js:7895:16
>       at replenish (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/build/cli.node.js:8415:25)
>       at iterateeCallback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/build/cli.node.js:8405:17)
>       at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/build/cli.node.js:8380:16
>       at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/build/cli.node.js:11332:13
>       at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/build/cli.node.js:69302:9
>       at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/build/cli.node.js:63982:7

When testing the callback function like below, everything goes well:

```
function () payable {
    uint amountPerEmployee = msg.value / employees.length;

    // Test with only the first item in the array, no loop
    employees[0].transfer(amountPerEmployee);
}
```

What is going on here? Is it the loop that is using too much gas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're walking off the end of the array with

`for(uint i = 0; i <= employees.length; i++)`

`employees[]` has exactly 3 rows, which are: `0, 1, 2`.

You let `i` be `3` which does not exist so it isn't happy.

A related tip for later as you go forward. You'll want to refactor the loop out of the picture completely for scalability reasons.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That fixed the problem. And thanks for the tip as well.